# Word Mail Merge - Filter Based on Partial Match of Text?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

I'm using Word 2010 and Excel 2010 to do a mail merge.

In the spreadsheet, the Employer field has variations of the employer name, such as:
 - SkyScraper
 - SkySraper Inc.
 - SkyScraper Mexico

In the mail merge, I want to filter records based just on "SkyScraper." So if any part of the employer name contains "SkyScraper," then filter the record.

I tried bracketing with quotes quotes ('SkyScraper' and "SkyScraper") but neither worked. If it should work, then that will be a different problem to solve; i.e., maybe the problem is with the Excel format (general vs text vs something else)?

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Are you in a position to use VBA (if only to set up a query that "does the right thing"? If not, how long can the Employer field be? And do you really want to allow "SkySraper", or are you really only looking for things with the spelling "skyscraper" but perhaps variant upper/lower case?

Comment: There's no character limit on the Employer field.

Comment: There's no character limit on the Employer field. "SkyScraper" is an example. There are other employer names to filter, too (i.e., in  a separate mail merge). It's possible that an employer name might be two words; three words is unlikely. Letter case does not matter. VBA is possible, though not my first choice. ~~ It just occurred to me that I could use Data>Text to Columns to split the field and then run the fllter. What do you think? Is there a better solution?

Comment: In the case where the Employer field could only be small, you could consider using field codes to do a number of comparisons using wild cards. With an unlimited length field it's not feasible. In all cases, modifying the data source is usually the easiest solution if you are in a position to do so. Add a column with an Excel formula to the spreadsheet, for example? The next best thing is to set up the data source using VBA - because you can use Jet (Access) SQL to get Excel data you can consider using a query with, e.g. SELECT instr(1,fieldname,'SkyScraper') to emulate a "contains".

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, @bibadia. The path of least resistance (and probably less error-prone results) is to add a column with a formula in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I was just looking at filtering for Excel again, and wondering whether you had actually tried the "Contains" option. (Go to MailMerge->Edit Recipient List->select the small dropdown in the header of the Employer column,select "Advanced...", select "Employer" from the list of fields, select "Contains" from the list of operators, and take it from there.